# jquery ajax call after javascript validation function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call my ajax code after my js validate() methods returns true on submit of the searchId button. But the ajax code is not executing. if I place an alert there it works fine.
Where I am doing wrong? Please help!!

here is my javascript code

```
  <script language="JavaScript">
  function validate()
  {
    var msg = "";
     //all my field validations are here
     msg += "o  Name is not a valid name.\n";

   if (msg > "") {
           alert(msg);
        return false;
      }
    else {
      return true;
      }
  }

 $(document).ready(function(){              
             $("#simple-post").click(function()
            {                
             $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
                {

                     // getting the values of both firstname and lastname        
                     var beginDate = $('input[name="txtBeginDate"]').val();        
                     var endDate = $('input[name="txtEndDate"]').val();   
                     var mdnVal = $('input[name="txtMsid"]').val();                      
                     // posting the values        
                     var dataString = 'beginDate=' + beginDate + '&endDate=' + endDate+ '&mdnVal=' + mdnVal;
                     alert(dataString);
                     var formURL = $(this).attr("action");  

                    //alert(formURL);                       
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        url : formURL,                          
                        dataType:'json',
                        async: false, 
                        data: dataString,
                        beforeSubmit: validate,
                        success:function(data){
                            queryObject = eval('(' + JSON.stringify(data) + ')');
                            queryObjectLen = queryObject.empdetails.length; 
                            drawChart();
                        },
                        error : function(xhr, type) {
                            alert('server error occoured')
                       }        
                    });
                  e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
                  e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
                });                 
                $("#ajaxform").submit(); //Submit the FORM
            });

         });
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform"  action="getData.jsp" onSubmit="return validate();"    method="POST">
   <Table>

         <input type="submit" name="action" value="Search" id="searchId">
         <input type="text" name="name" id="id"  size="10" maxlength="10">
                   //other input fields    

      </table>
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="simple-post">Run Code</button>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

I have updated my code, i can submit my form, but the validation not working. I am using beforeSubmit: validate, still i dont see my validation messages. Please help.

Comment: `msg > ""` what do you think is happening there??

Comment: In your validate() function, where is msg getting set? What is its value supposed to be?

Comment: @RUJordan, I have edited my HTML and validate().

Comment: You didn't even touch what I was referencing. Basically, you're running a condition that says "if whatever is inside `msg` is greater than an empty string". Does that make sense? It shouldn't.

Comment: @user2436956 did you mean `msg != ""` instead of `msg > ""`? and where is `"#ajaxform"` and `"#simple-post"` elements on your _html_?

Comment: I had forgotten to update my HTML. now it is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fxed the problem. Added a Submit button markup  and removed Run Code. Changed onsubmit to onclick on the submit button. Again removed $("#simple-post").click(function() form my jquery code.This seems to be working fine now.

Thanks to this post

[Validate a form with javascript before submitting with ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119450/validate-a-form-with-javascript-before-submitting-with-ajax)